# Webhook for whatsapp business api client different business manager

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, whatsapp

Our app already have business_management, whatsapp_business_messaging, whatsapp_business_management approval from facebook. The issue is when we try to subscribe to any business whatsapp number outside our business manager it gives us error of         "error_user_title": "App not linked to a Business",
"error_user_msg": "Your App is not linked to a Business or the Business doesn't have access to the WhatsApp Business Account.",

Comment: Have you created facebook developer app for whatsapp business? There you have to provide the business account.

Comment: yes sure and it's already connected to. and everything is working fine the issue is with adding whatsapp business account from different business manager that we don't have permission on

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?